# Animating opacity not working properly

Tags: jquery, fade

I am attempting to animate the opacity of an element with the following code;

```
window.setInterval(function(){
    var target = $('.before'),
    opacity = target.css('opacity');

    target.fadeTo(600, (opacity==1?0:1))
    }, 5000);
```

When the opacity is animating from 1 to 0 it works fine, but when animating from 0 to 1 it does not animate at all, it just instantly changes from 0 to 1.

I have tried various methods using fadeTo() animate() toggle() but to no avail

Using fadeToggle() works as expected but isn't really an option as it adds display: none to the element after the animation is complete which messes with the layout of the page.

**EDIT**

SOLVED:

The website I am working on was using jQuery 1.4.4, updating to 1.10.1 fixed this issue.

Comment: Mmm... could it be a browser problem? Tried your code in Chrome and it's working ok: http://jsbin.com/epehul/2/edit

Answer (score 0):

try using `window.setInterval(function(){
    $('.before').animate($('.before').css('opacity', 1?0:1), 1000);
    }, 5000);`

Comment: Adding the .val() to the end seemed to stop the animation from working completely.

Answer (score 0):

What browsers are you intending to support? This can be done *very* easily with css - just add/remove a class with jQuery, then use css transitions to handle the opacity fade. The opacity on/off would still work in lte IE8, but it just won't fade.

Alternatively, you could use fadeToggle and add 'display: block !important;' (or whatever display you require) to the element.